# Program testing approach

Tags: c#

I have project that need some UITest and UnitTest. If i should do it like in code below. What problems can arise with such approach? Or it's better to use small isolated UITest and small isolated UnitTest. Maybe somebody already faced with this approach. Or maybe it is greate paradigm. I think that this  approach will be Tightly coupled and more complex than the project.

```
namespace TestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string commandLineArgs = string.Empty;

            switch (commandLineArgs)
            {
                case "UI":
                    // Run library with UI on WPF
                    break;
                case "SeriaApi":
                    // Run library without UI
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        void ConnectDevices(string controller1, string controller2);
    }

    public class ImplementationForUI : ITest
    {
        public void ConnectDevices(string controller1, string controller2)
        {
            // UI Test Realization, make the same that ImplementationForSerialApi.ConnectDevices with WPF wrapper
        }
    }

    public class ImplementationForSerialApi : ITest
    {
        public void ConnectDevices(string controller1, string controller2)
        {
            // SerialApi Test Realization, make the same that ImplementationForUI.ConnectDevices but in console
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private ITest ITest;
        public Test(ITest instance)
        {
            ITest = instance;
        }
        public void RunTestCase1()
        {
            ITest.ConnectDevices(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to try: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: '@JeffO when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

> Or it's better to use small isolated UITest and small isolated UnitTest.

Yes, that's better.

For unit tests, you want to test the smallest possible pieces that are still functional (i.e. not implementation details).

Once you've established that all the pieces work individually, you may have a few more tests that make sure the parts work together correctly. At some point you have verified that your library works.

Now you do the same with your user interfaces: mock out the library and just test the UI-logic. What and how much of it you should test is a whole new topic (which you'll find has been discussed on this page quite a bit already).

Finally, all that's left to do is the startup (your main method). See those two comments you have in there? (Run library with UI /  Run library without UI). These should really be replaced with `runLibraryWithUI();` and `runLibraryWithoutUI();`.

If you're doing more than two simple function calls, separate this startup sequence out into a new module and test that module. Eventually, your main method should be so simple that you don't really need a test.

Answer (score -2):

Looks ugly to me. Can't you separate out the SeriaApi code into a separate library with its own unit tests, then use that library from your main UI application?

Comment: this reads more like a comment, see [answer]

Comment: Unfortunately Im new to this and I cant add comments